# What might be the reason for Gack Id -2137186094 when deploying KnowledgeValidationStatus standardValueSet picklist values

Tags: knowledge, lightning-knowledge, knowledgevalidationstatus, validationstatus

I am trying to deploy KnowledgeValidationStatus.standardValueSet-meta.xml field and I am receiving an error

```
Error KnowledgeValidationStatus An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1338364512-158639 (-2137186094)
```

What might be reason?

Looks like I didn't receive it when performing manual deployment but only during CI/CD validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the problem arised when I tried to add `Not Validated` picklist value.

Since this picklist cannot be retrieved, it is hard to guess the correct metadata file for it.

When I changed from

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StandardValueSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <sorted>false</sorted>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>NotValidated</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Not Validated</label>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>InReview</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>In Review</label>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>ReadyForApproval</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Ready For Approval</label>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Approved</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Approved</label>
    </standardValue>
</StandardValueSet>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StandardValueSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <sorted>false</sorted>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Not Validated</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Not Validated</label>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>InReview</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>In Review</label>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>ReadyForApproval</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Ready For Approval</label>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Approved</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Approved</label>
    </standardValue>
</StandardValueSet>
```

the error has gone.

Comment: I love that you post these self-answered questions once you resolve a vexing problem

Comment: I learned today a new word: vexing. Didn't know its meaning before